# Merging multiple CSV files and dropping duplicates by field

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I need to match data from multiple CSV files. 
For example, if I have three CSV files.

input 1 csv

```
PANYNJ LGA WEST 1,available, LGA West GarageFlushing
PANYNJ LGA WEST 4,unavailable,LGA West Garage
iPark - Tesla,unavailable,530 E 80th St
```

input 2 csv

```
PANYNJ LGA WEST 4,unavailable,LGA West Garage
PANYNJ LGA WEST 5,available,LGA West Garage
```

input 3 csv

```
PANYNJ LGA WEST 5,available,LGA West Garage
imPark - Tesla,unavailable,611 E 83rd St
```

The first column is `name`, the second one is `status`, and the last one is `address`. I would like to merge these three documents into one csv file if they have the same name. My desire output file is like

output csv

```
PANYNJ LGA WEST 1,available, LGA West GarageFlushing
PANYNJ LGA WEST 4,unavailable,LGA West Garage
iPark - Tesla,unavailable,530 E 80th St
PANYNJ LGA WEST 5,available,LGA West Garage
imPark - Tesla,unavailable,611 E 83rd St
```

I'm trying to fix this with `pandas` or `CSV` but I'm unsure how to go about this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pandas`, you can use `pd.concat` followed by `pd.drop_duplicates`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

str1 = StringIO("""PANYNJ LGA WEST 1,available, LGA West GarageFlushing
PANYNJ LGA WEST 4,unavailable,LGA West Garage
iPark - Tesla,unavailable,530 E 80th St""")

str2 = StringIO("""PANYNJ LGA WEST 4,unavailable,LGA West Garage
PANYNJ LGA WEST 5,available,LGA West Garage""")

str3 = StringIO("""PANYNJ LGA WEST 5,available,LGA West Garage
imPark - Tesla,unavailable,611 E 83rd St""")

# replace str1, str2, str3 with 'file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(str1, header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(str2, header=None)
df3 = pd.read_csv(str3, header=None)

res = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)\
        .drop_duplicates(0)

print(res)

                   0            1                         2
0  PANYNJ LGA WEST 1    available   LGA West GarageFlushing
1  PANYNJ LGA WEST 4  unavailable           LGA West Garage
2      iPark - Tesla  unavailable             530 E 80th St
4  PANYNJ LGA WEST 5    available           LGA West Garage
6     imPark - Tesla  unavailable             611 E 83rd St
```

Comment: @EuniceTT, No problem. Please feel free to accept (green tick on left) if this helped.

Comment: Could you mind answering me another question about how to change the left line "0 1 2 4 6" to " 0 1 2 3 4 "?

Comment: @EuniceTT, Sure, add `.reset_index(drop=True)` to the end.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_and_dedupe(files_to_combine, output_file, filter_column, fieldnames):
    '''
    Combine multiple CSV files into one final CSV file, removing duplicates
    based on one column that uniquely identifies the entry (ex: name, ID, email, etc.)
    '''
    added = []
    with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = fieldnames
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator = '\n')
        writer.writeheader()
        for file in files_to_combine:
            with open(file, newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                for row in reader:
                    if row[filter_column] not in added:
                        added.append(row[filter_column])
                        writer.writerow(row)
                    else:
                        print('Duplicate')
                        continue
```

```
Here is a function I created to do exactly what you want.

files_to_combine is a list of the csv files Ex: ['miami_clients.csv', 'los_angeles_clients.csv']

output_file is the name of the output file

filter_column is the column to uniquely identify entries to check for duplicates

fieldnames is the list of field names for the CSV files
```